# Had Conway's Game of Life or any C-A been demonstrated to generate non-repeating pattern?

Tags: turing-completeness, cellular-automata

As we know, Conway's Game of Life is Turing-complete. And Turing-complete systems can be used to calculate irrational numbers such as $\sqrt{2}$, $\pi$, $e$, etc. which have non-repeating digits.

So it might be natural to reach the conclusion that Conway's Game of Life can be used to generate non-repeating digits.

To limit the scope of this question and not make it open-ended and opinion-based, I'll be asking: has there been research on cellular automata:

- generating infinite non-repeating patterns,
- by programming it to carry out computation similar to square root and base-2 logarithm over fixed-point numbers? (these computations are the easiest I've thought of that can be carried out on fixed-point numbers with sufficient numericall accuracy)

Comment: Are you asking about Conway's Life specifically, or cellular automata in general? And what do you mean by "generating infinite non-repeating patterns"? Two gliders traveling in opposite directions is a pattern that never repeats exactly, but I suspect you're looking for something more complex.

Comment: @IlkkaTörmä Edited.

Comment: I'll just leave this here: https://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Pi_calculator

Comment: A recent example is a paper by Kutrib and Malcher, One-Dimensional Pattern Generation by Cellular Automata, Cellular Automata (ACRI 2020), LNCS 12599, doi: [10.1007/978-3-030-69480-7_6](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-69480-7_6). From its abstract: "*we [...] look at cellular automata towards their ability to generate formal languages, here called patterns, within certain time constraints. As an example we describe a construction of a cellular automaton that generates prefixes of the well-known Thue-Morse sequence within real time.*" Thue-Morse is a famous non-repeating pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Rule 110 is a cellular automaton that is Turing complete, hence it can generate non-repeating patterns.  Since it is Turing complete it can certainly compute the square root of a fixed-point number.

Comment: I might be mistaken but I don't see the "by programming it" part in your answer.

Comment: @DannyNiu It is Turing complete, just write "the program" of your choice as a Turing machine, and use the Turing completeness construction. If you want infinite non repeating pattern you can calculate $\pi$ or something similar.